# What does the last condition in the following corollary about monomial orderings mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

In class, I was given the following useful corollary in judging whether a given ordering ">" is a monomial ordering or not.

> Let > be a relation on $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$ that satisfies
>
> i) > is a total ordering on $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$.
>
> ii) if $\alpha > \beta$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$, then $\alpha + \gamma > \beta + \gamma$.
>
> Then > is a well-ordering if and only if

(Here comes the statement I don't understand)

> $\alpha \geq 0$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$.

What I don't understand is, $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$ simply, does it not already mean that $\alpha \geq 0$? Because $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$, the $_{\geq 0}$ I thought it means that "every entry of the $n$-tuple in $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$ takes integer values greater than or equal to $0$."

So I cannot think of any $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$ that would violate $\alpha \geq 0$. The possibilities are

1. I am misunderstanding what is meant by $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$.
2. I am misunderstanding what is meant by $\alpha \geq 0$ (I am taking it to mean that every entry is $\geq 0$).

Please kindly elaborate on what this condition is saying and maybe give me an example of when it is violated. Is there a type of order > that would make this false?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following weight order on $\mathbb Z_{\ge0}^2$: $$(a_1,a_2)\ge(b_1,b_2)\text{ iff }a_1-a_2\sqrt2\ge b_1-b_2\sqrt2.$$
Then $(2,-1)\ge(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The $0$ here is the zero multi-index $(0, \ldots, 0) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$, so the third axiom means that $\alpha \geq (0, \ldots, 0)$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$.  This is just a condition we place on the partial order $\geq$ on $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$: we insist, that the zero tuple must be the smallest multi-index with respect to $\geq$.  In particular, it does *not* mean $\alpha_i \geq 0$ for all $i$.

Alternatively, since the multi-indices are exponents of monomials, i.e., $\alpha \leftrightarrow x^\alpha = x_1^{\alpha_1} x_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$, the third axiom is equivalent to $m \geq 1$ for all monomials $m \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.